# What is the Android Keycode for dismissing the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

Does anybody know the keycode for dismissing the soft keyboard in Android?

I have gone through the doc of KeyEvent class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND

but could not find an appropriate one.

By the keycode to dismiss the soft keyboard I mean the one on the soft keyboard that is able to close the keyboard panel rather than the "back" key on the bottom of the device.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: There's no such thing. To close the keyboard, c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: The soft key you describe is implementation specific, not all Android keyboards have it.

Answer (score 1):

this answer may works for you...Try this

```
set android:codes="-3" to a key for dismissing
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you mean: im not sure

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

this will turn the return key into the done key to dismiss the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to close it in like an onClick method?

I think what you may want is this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(text.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: No. There is a key to dismiss keyboard on the left bottom corner of softkeyboard. He wants the code of that key. Even i am trying the same now. I guess only back, backspace are detectable

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```